# Timed caching in Vertx

Tags: java, caching, vert.x

I've just been starting out with Vertx. I wonder if there's a way to store/cache a response data for a period of time?

For example, the first time a user calls my API, it will query the database on the server and return a data. I want to save/cache this data to a local file (or memory) on the server for, for example, 3 hours. During these 3 hours, if any other user make another call to the API, it will use the cached data instead. After 3 hours, the cached data reset.

I tried searching on Google for solutions like Vertx Redis, or StaticHandler, but they seem over-complicated, and don't seem to match my needs?

Is there a simple way to achieve this?

Comment: I think the simplest way to do it is storing the data in a `Map` and use Vert.x `setTimer` to evict cache.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! How do I achieve this? What class does `setTimer` belong to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a cache (with some `Map` maybe) and `Vertx::setTimer` to invalidate it after 3 hours. Assuming you are using `Router`:

```
 router.get("/things/:id").handler(rc -> {
     String id = rc.pathParam("id");
     List result = cache.getThing(id);
     if (result == null) {
       result = getThingFromDatabase(id);
       cache.saveThing(result);
       vertx.setTimer(10800000, t -> { // <-- 3 hours
           cache.invalidateThing(id);
       });
     }
     return result;
 });
```

Comment: Thanks! I end up using `AsyncMap` instead, but this also did the trick for me (and kind of gave me a direction to go)!

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to reinvent wheel for Vert.x again. There are plenty of tools out there to do caching for you and [Google Guava cache](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CachesExplained) is the one that should suite your need very well.

In your verticle you define a `cache` and access your DB though it. The cache does the rest:

```
LoadingCache<Key, Graph> cache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
       .expireAfterWrite(3, TimeUnit.HOURS)
       .build(
           new CacheLoader<Key, SomeClass>() {
             @Override
             public SomeClass load(Key key) throws AnyException {
               return loadYourData(key);
             }
           });
```

then whenever you need to get your data:

```
SomeClass obj = cache.get(key);
```